# How to trace history of ethereum state varaibles?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

One of the much appraised features of blockchain among other things is traceability of data
stored on the blockchain priced on records being immutable i think.

I am trying to find out how state changes can be traced practically on the ethereum blockchain.
To explain my question, take the following smart contract as example

```
contract SimpleStorage {
    uint storedData;

    function set(uint x) public {
        storedData = x;
    }

    function get() public view returns (uint) {
        return storedData;
    }
}
```

In this contract the focus is on the `storedData` state variable. Lets assume that 
the value has changed severally at countless times overtime.
So how can one trace out the history of this `storedData` to see all the values that has been assigned to it at different points in time.
I am looking for a practical way this is done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two ways to potentially track how a state variable has changed over time:

1) The contract has been developed so that when said variable is modified its previous state is added to an array which contains all previous states.
ex. check this contract events:
https://etherscan.io/address/0x3958b4ec427f8fa24eb60f42821760e88d485f7f#events

[image]

2) the contract has been developed so when the state variable is modified it fires an Event that logs said transaction. 
Take a look to this post in consensys about events:

https://media.consensys.net/technical-introduction-to-events-and-logs-in-ethereum-a074d65dd61e

The article presents three use cases for events:

> "*First, using an event to simply get a return value from a contract
>   function invoked with sendTransaction(). Second, using an event as an
>   asynchronous trigger with data, that can notify an observer such as a
>   UI. Third, using an event to write logs in the blockchain as a cheaper
>   form of storage.*"

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. So it appears there's no out of the box standard api that does that.

Comment: I don't know an API that directly provides the history of a variable